# How to add official website link? In Huawei AGC

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, appgallery-connect, agconnect-functions

How to add official website link in listing page.

I saw few apps have website link in app information. I want to add website link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer below link for above problem-
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-help-configure-appinfo-0000001100086630

[image]